# Connecting Log-in credentials to retrieved data in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, parameter-passing

I've been encountering problems with passing variables form different views. What i want is whenever a user logs in his id, It would automatically retrieve the data that is connected to that ID from the database.

Apparently, I have 3 controllers for my login (c_home,c_login and c_verifylogin), 1 model (m_login) and 1 view (v_home)

Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Controllers:
c_login

```
 function index() {
        $this->load->helper(array('form','html'));
        $this->load->view('v_login'); //load view for login
    }
```

c_home

```
   function index() {
        if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
        {
            $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
            $data['studentid'] = $session_data['studentid'];
            $this->load->view('v_display', $data);
        } else {
        //If no session, redirect to login page
            redirect('c_login', 'refresh');
        }
    }

    function getGrades() {
       $data['query'] = $this->m_login->result_getGrades(); 
       $this->load->view('v_display', $data);
    }


    function logout() {
         //remove all session data
         $this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in');
         $this->session->sess_destroy();
         redirect('c_login', 'refresh');
     }
```

c_verifylogin

```
function index() {

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('studentid', 'studentid', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_database');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('v_login');
        } else {
            //Go to private area
            redirect('c_home', 'refresh');
        }       
 }


 function check_database() {
     //Field validation succeeded.  Validate against database
     $studentid = $this->input->post('studentid');
     $password = $this->input->post('password');
     //query the database
     $result = $this->login->login($studentid, $password);
     if($result) {
         $sess_array = array();
         foreach($result as $row) {
             //create the session
             $sess_array = array('studentid' => $row->studentid);
             //set session with value from database
             $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
             }
      return TRUE;
      } else {
          //if form validate false
          $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', 'Invalid username or password');
          return FALSE;
      }
  }
```

m_login

```
function login($studentid, $password) 
    {
        //create query to connect user login database
        $this->db->select('studentid, password');
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->where('studentid', $studentid);
        $this->db->where('password', md5($password));
        $this->db->limit(1);

        //get query and processing
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if($query->num_rows() == 1) { 
            return $query->result(); //if data is true
        } else {
            return false; //if data is wrong
        }
    }
         function result_getGrades()
    {
          $this->db->select('grades.blockcode,subjectblocking.subjectcode,subjects.description,grades.final');
          $this->db->from('grades');
          $this->db->join('subjectblocking','grades.blockcode=subjectblocking.blockcode');
          $this->db->join('subjects','subjectblocking.subjectcode=subjects.subjectcode');
          $this->db->where('studentid', '2013-F0218');
          $this->db->where('sem', '1');
          $this->db->where('sy','2013-2014');
          $query=$this->db->get();
          return $query->result();

    }
```

Views: v_display

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>
   <title>Simple Login with CodeIgniter - Private Area</title>
 </head>
    <body>
      <h1>Home</h1>
   <h2>Welcome <?php echo $studentid; ?>!</h2>
   <a href="c_home/logout">Logout</a>

            <table class="table">

                <thead>
                    <th>Subject Code</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Grade</th>
                </thead>
        <?php foreach ($query as $row){ ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $row->subjectcode;?><br></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->description;?><br></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->final;?><br></td>
                    </tr>

        <?php } ?>  
            </table>

    </body>
</html>
```

and the error that i have encountered is

> Message: Undefined variable: query

and

> Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: can you give the url where you found this error .. 
because in your code i can't find the calling of login function where v_display is loading

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I see is, that you don't name the table in your query:

Change:

```
$query = $this->db->get();
```

To this:

```
$query = $this->db->get("your_table_name_here);
```

Comment: Okay. but its still working even if i did not define the table name

Answer (score 0):

When I read your code I feel headache.
You can actually just put the verify login in your `c_login` and not create another `c_verify` controller.

To make it sense
Try to refactor your code like the connection will be like this

```
c_home = private page that can only be access if the user is login
c_login = verify if the input of user passed and check the data from database.
```

**To summarize**

`c_login` will compose of this functions :

1. verify user input
2. check database through m_login

**Note**: Your logout should be put in the core so that all controller can use it

In your `c_home`, you just need to create a model that will get the data from database and pass it to your

`$data['grades'] = $your_model->get_grades`

the variable grades will now be pass to view using $data.

**Note**: You don't need to create another function to just get the data. What you only need is the model because that is the purpose of model and just pass it in your variable in your controller.

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/

**Summarize :**

> From Model -> Controller -> View  Get data from model pass it in
>   controller show it in view